# Omission of repeated "the"

Tags: articles, ellipses

Which one is grammatically correct?

1. The design of trading mechanisms, the management of uncertainty and the protection of privacy are the main issues in....
2. The design of trading mechanisms, management of uncertainty and protection of privacy are the main issues in....

Comment: What is your specific grammatical concern?  Depending on desired style and context, it's hard to see what makes one of these unacceptable.

Comment: Without nit-picking, both are "correct".

Comment: The latter is clumsy. I would word such a sentence as _Trading mechanism design, uncertainty management and privacy protection are the main issues in ..._ I would say that the articles are necessary (as in the former) due to the complexity. In other cases the article can be used as a single 'bracket' : The author and designer, Joe Bloggs, will be here shortly.